# Is it the memory or the mainboard?

Tags: 64-bit, memory, motherboard

I just assembled my own 64-bit windows system.

After finishing my system I upgraded with 4gb ram (2+2)

and I started getting frequent bsod, when unplugging one memory module system seems stable.

I did memcheck on all memory and harddisk without anything being discovered.

Is it still reasonable to believe that the memory might be faulty or should I look at the mainboard for problems.

4gb memory seems stable but 6gb does not.

Comment: What memory test are you using?  Use Memtest86+ if you are using something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) overnight and see what it shows. If it shows anything, move the memory modules around (so that each module is in a different slot), then run it again. If the errors stay in the same place, it's the slot, if they move with the module, it's the module.

Comment: well it didn't take long. Thanks for the link to memtest86+, when testing the simm memory it was glowing bright red with errors. same with the other simm but different error.

Answer (score 8):

If it is fine when one memory is out, I would say that the memory has the problem.

Try putting in just the one that causes the error and leave the memory checker running for about 24 hours, or long enough for you to be certain.

A lot of people use memtest or similar, but then only run for 5 minutes - whilst this will show you really bad modules, it does not show the modules that just have slight faults.

-- Edit,

I wrote my answer simply by saying in my opinion, the most common problem. As others have said, it could also be the motherboard itself.

I have to say that it is very rare as problems with regards to the socket usually prevents the machine from turning on and power problems usually give some sort of BIOS alert next time you turn on - however, it does happen and should be mentioned just incase.

Once you know that a stick of memory is fine, you can try swapping it with the stick that you think has the errors. If it is still showing errors, it is the stick - however, if it is fine then put the working stick in the other socket.

If after this you are still getting errors, it could be a faulty motherboard.

At this point, if you have done any power tweaking in the BIOS, undo it or return the BIOS to safe settings. If you haven't done anything then I think the motherboard has problems.

Comment: +agreed, except that I don't think you can say the memory has the problem until you do the long memtest, though it's pretty likely.  The motherboard's RAM slot could be the issue, not providing stable voltage to the RAM module.

Comment: @calavera - Agreed... I should of gone in to more detail!

Comment: In addition to already suggested, try swapping places of memory modules or placing them in different slots. It sometimes helps.

Comment: Could also just be his hardware combo.  I once had a stable OC on a machine with 12GB of RAM, but when I added another GPU (which was not OCed) the OC became unstable.  Had to dial back my OC to keep all 12GB of RAM.  RAM still sounds like the issue here, or power supply to the RAM.  Make sure to use Memtest86+ to check, and swap out sticks like everyone is saying.

Comment: Good reply, thanks for you time! I approved first answer as "correct" since he included the link.